# Хуки Wordpress на сохранение рубрики

Tags: php, wordpress

В Wordpress  есть хук на сохранение поста: `'save_post'` 
Есть ли стандартный xук на сохранение рубрики/ таксономии?

Подробнее. У меня есть несколько кастомных таксономий ,  нужно повесить действие при сохранении категории (добавлении новой, или изменении старой).
Поэтому вижу два варианта либо использовать стандартный хук на это дело,если он есть ( найти что нибудь по этому вопросу я не смог) либо задать свой хук на это дело и тогда вопрос встает как это сделать, если учесть что кастомные таксономии я создавал методом `register_taxonomy('city', 'post',  array(..))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, все ссылки по данной теме на английском языке. Привожу их. Дополнительно кратко опишу что и в каком порядке выполняется.

При создании/изменении термов вызывается функция [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term). В ней последовательно вызываются следующие хуки:

- фильтр [`pre_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_insert_term/) (вызывается сразу после входа в функцию);
- действие [`edit_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_term/) (вызывается перед обновлением строки в базе);
- действие [`edited_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_term/) (вызывается после обновления строки в базе);
- действие [`create_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_term/) (вызывается после создания нового терма, но перед очищением кеша термов);
- действие `create_{taxonomy}`, где `{taxonomy}` — это "тег" (`slug`) таксономии;
- фильтр [`term_id_filter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_id_filter/);
- действие [`created_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_term/) (вызывается после создания нового терма и после очищения кеша термов);
- действие `created_{taxonomy}`, где `{taxonomy}` — это "тег" (`slug`) таксономии;